# GraphQL - Global field resolvers

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-server

Say I have the following schema:

```
type CodeName {
  code: Int!
  name: String!
}

type Person {
  id: Int!
  weapon: Weapon
  hat: Hat
  codeName: CodeName!
}

type Weapon {
  id: Int!
  type: String!
  codeName: CodeName!
}

type Hat {
  id: Int!
  size: Int!
  codeName: CodeName!
}

type Query {
  Person(id: Int!): Person!
  Weapon(id: Int!): Weapon!
  Hat(id: Int!): Hat!
}
```

then, I would define my resolvers like so:

```js
const resolvers = {
  Weapon: {
    codeName: CodeNameResolver,
  },
  Hat: {
    codeName: CodeNameResolver,
  },
  Person: {
    codeName: CodeNameResolver,
    weapon: WeaponResolver,
    hat: HatResolver
  },
  Query: {
    Person: PersonResolver,
    Weapon: WeaponResolver,
    Hat: HatResolver,
  }
}
```

However, I have to repeat `codeName: CodeNameResolver` multiple times in the code, every time I have a field whose type is `CodeName`.
Is there a way to use a global field resolver, or type resolver, so that I don't have to do that?

Comment: Why would multiple different types have the same field that is accessed exactly in the same way on them? If that's really the case, yes, specify it multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

If your resolver functions are identical, then you're about as DRY as you're going to get. GraphQL doesn't have a mechanism for globally specifying a resolver based on the field's type.

You could potentially accomplish this using [graphql-middleware](https://github.com/prisma-labs/graphql-middleware)

```
const codeNameMiddleware = async (resolve, root, args, context, info) => {
  if (info.returnType.toString() === 'CodeName!') {
    // resolve the field here
    return someValue
  }
  return resolve(root, args, context, info)
}
```

You should be cautious when applying this sort of pattern, though. A field's type only describes the shape of the data it returns -- it says nothing about how that data is fetched. Even if all your resolvers for `CodeName` fields look the same now, that may not be the case in the future.

Comment: Why is it so dry? The parents hold a `codeNameId` field, I want to query `CodeName` from the database using the `codeNameId` on the parent. That logic will obviously be shared across all parents